# How to disable edit links/tasks for mobile theme?

Tags: theming

I have a separate sub domain and theme for a mobile version of my site. I would like to disable the edit links/tabs for nodes if viewed from that subdomain/theme, but still allow users from editing in the main theme.

Any help or tips will be appreciated.

Comment: what Drupal version do you use ?

Comment: It's for D6, but will have the same issue with a D7 site as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items should be disabled, if they are usually enabled, but not useful in that particular circumstance. For example, a submit button could be disabled when the form does not validate. Having an item that is permanently disabled raises the question why the item is displayed at all.

If you want to hide the items, you can do this using CSS if there is an appropriate CSS selector. Have a look at the HTML to figure that out.

For Drupal 4.7.x, 5.x and 6.x, you can also remove the links as described on the drupal.org page [*Remove unwanted tabs from pages*](http://drupal.org/node/68792).

Note that both methods only remove the link from the page. They do not prevent users from actually editing the page (e.g. by entering the URL manually).

Comment: I don't just want to hide the links. I don't want the edit form eg. to be accessible from the mobile site/theme at all, just from the main site/theme. But I think I have a better solution - to redirect those pages in .htaccess to the main site.

Comment: Oh yeah, almost forgot. The method described at [Remove unwanted tabs from pages](http://drupal.org/node/68792) might work, but it seems hackish, and doing it with hook_menu_alter removes tabs for both themes, so won't work in my case.